# Signal: when will such a situation happen?

Tags: c, linux, signals

```
if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN) 
    signal(SIGINT, sig_int);
```

I have seen this code several times. And it confuses me. Doing this, the process catches the signal only if the signal is not currently being ignored.

My question is:

1. I think `signal(SIGINT, sig_int);` will never be executed unless there is an error in the first signal function, is it right?
2. In which situation `(signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)` happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line by line,

`if (signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) != SIG_IGN)`

The call to `signal` returns the previous action.  So what is happening here is we're setting the signal handler to be `SIG_IGN` (i.e. ignore the signal), then checking the return value to see if it was already being ignored.  If it was not ignored previously, then...

`signal(SIGINT, sig_int);`

...happens.

So, expressed a different way, "Check to see if SIGINT was being ignored, and if was not being ignored, set the signal handler to sig_int."  It's a little bit weird to actually set the signal to SIG_IGN to compare the return value in the first line, but that's what is happening.

EDIT:  signal() can return SIG_ERR as well, which is something else to consider.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. Is there any way to achieve this by easy-to-read code?

Comment: Probably the safest thing to do with this code is to put a comment near it and not touch it!  Who knows how sensitive it is to changes, given the global impact of changing signal().

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly right, `signal` will return its previous sig value (SIG_IGN) or SIG_ERR if it breaks. So what the code is doing is saying, if there is a problem handing the SIG_IGN the error (which records and ignores it) then the program catches the signal again and passes it to the function sig_int which must handle it in some other way.

source: http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal

As for when it will happen, The website [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Basic-Signal-Handling.html) indicates this:

If signal can't honor the request, it returns SIG_ERR instead. The following errno error conditions are defined for this function:

```
EINVAL
You specified an invalid signum; or you tried to ignore or provide 
a handler for SIGKILL or SIGSTOP.
```

Since SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or handelled, id say the only way the second command would be called is if somehow SIG_IGN was wrong?